# Menus become cutoff and show as "..."

Tags: menu

Sometimes when I go to open a menu item, it cuts off the text and I see '...'. Here it is happening on QkSMS but it happens on other apps too. Is there a way to fix it?

Here is a picture of it happening. I have an Xperia Z3 on T-Mobile running 4.4.4.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Which other apps do this? Does it happen anywhere else in QK?

Comment: It happens to all the menus in QKSMS. If I open and close them a few times, it begins to work but this is not for just QKSMS. It happens on other apps as well.
Edit: Are you Moez Bhatti? Creator of QKSMS?

Comment: Seems like it could be app-specific (or library-specific, if all affected apps are using the same app bar/overflow menu libraries).